# Interacting with presenting view and UIPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I would like to be able to tap a button in VC1 and have VC2 animate out of the button. While VC2 is present, I want to be able to still interact with VC1. I have tried using an Animator adopting the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol (which I am not yet comfortable working with), but doing so disables touch interaction with VC1. I started investigating UIPresentationController, but that appears to be strictly for modal presentations where VC1 interaction would be disabled. My illustration looks like this:

```
 ------------
|            |
|    VC1     |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|  |------|  |
|  | VC2  |  |
|  |------|  |
 ------------
```

Using the approach in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051839/interact-with-presenting-controller-whilst-a-modal-controller-is-displayed) doesn't work for two reasons. The first is that VC2 does not extend to the bottom of the screen and second is that VC2 needs look like the button pressed in VC1 expands to reveal it.

What method can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: You can achieve this by **addChildViewController** in VC1.  Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to answer it.